# What is this.myClick() doing in this vue js method and how could I test it?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-component

Currently in vue code I have a page that has the following line:

```
<MyButton :my-click="generateSomeValues"/>
```

generateSomeValues, generates values and these then get set on the prop in the component.

MyButton is a component and inside it, it has the following:

```
    @click.prevent="myloginButtonClicked" (The button has a click event which called the code below)
```

We then have the props and a methods:

```
      props: {
         myClick: {
           type: Function,
           default: undefined,
    },
  },

      methods: {
        async myloginButtonClicked() {
          if (typeof this.myClick !== 'undefined') {
            this.myClick();
          }
        }
      },
```

Im trying to understand what this.myClick() is doing and how this could be tested using Jest. Looking at it, I would have thought myClick was just a prop and not a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code snippet

```
props: {
    myClick: {
        type: Function,
        default: undefined,
    }
},
```

You have indeed defined `myClick` as a prop. It is not a method. It is, however, a prop that happens to be a function, which means that it can be called.

To test it, you can use a Mock function

```
const mockMyClick = jest.fn(() => {});
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyButton, {
  propsData: { myClick: mockMyClick }
});
const button = wrapper.find('button') // or whatever
button.trigger('click')
expect(mockMyClick.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
```

Comment: That makes sense. To confirm how to I test both the scenario of myClick being both defined i.e it call this.myClick() and then the scenario or myClick being undefined thus it wont call this.myClick(). Thanks for your help.